# How to manage error handling like getlasterror?

Tags: c++, error-handling

There is a library I developed. (Observer pattern and boost.signals2)
Briefly the logic : Many C ++ modules register with a unique ID.
subscriber             s1(service,"unique_id")
There are a lot of registers modules. They have unique id. 
With my Publisher interface, I receive data from the user and send it to all or one of these modules. No problem so far.
There are some situations. I checked in my own library. In some cases, the broadcast cannot be made and an error occurs. I have to report this back to the user of the publisher interface.

```
publisher publisher_one;
std::int32_t ret_val ;
ret_val =  publisher_one.publish_notifications(oss.str());
if(ret_val == 0){
    std::cout<<"Succsess" << "\n";

}
else{
    std::cout <<"Fail" << "\n";
         /*todo
        * Control error
    */ 
}
publish_notifications there are some if check for error status
```

I am an independent library and cannot have a back enum return value.
How is the best solution? Is there an example for this?
As far as I know, there is a solution on the windows side like getlasterror. Can I apply this to the linux side?
Thank  you

Comment: Is there a reason not to use exceptions in this example ?

Comment: if you really want it, look at how `errno` works, but you need to be cautious with thread-safety. But yes, why no exceptions?